# How to configure the "history" tab on TeamCity, so it shows all the successful builds

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to configure the history tab in TeamCity? Currently, it just shows the last 3 successful builds.

Comment: are you referring to the build history of an individual build configuration? if yes, then i can see 20 builds per page using TC 7.0.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty sure TeamCity will show you everything in the history that has not been "cleaned up" (deleted). To adjust your clean-up settings, go to:

- **Administration** > **Build History Clean-up** (under Project-related Settings)
- Under **Configure clean-up rules for specific build configurations**, edit the **Default clean-up rule** (or the rules for a specific Project/Build Config under **Manage clean-up rules for:**)
- Make sure the **Clean history** or **Clean everything** settings are to your liking.

Note that pinned builds are excluded from these settings.

I think the default setting in the distribution is to clean everything older than the 20th successful build.

For more info, go here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Clean-Up